# How to access facebook API without creating facebook App

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, facebook-graph-api, streamsets

I'm currently researching on how to use facebook API and collect its data thru streamsets and store it to S3. But facebook requires developer to create an app and verify it which somehow not applicable to what I'm doing right now. Is there other way to do this? like different process to access the Facebook API without creating an App?

Answer (score 3):

While I'm happy to stand to be corrected, I do not believe this can be done.

It's not like you have to actually MAKE an app with your "app" - the app is simply an API key that has some associated data with it like titles and URLs and such. This also helps them track your usage and make sure you're following the rules, and block your key if you don't.